# How to end edit mode in DataGridView cell when mouse moves away from cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The default behavior of ending edit mode in one cell by clicking the mouse on some other object is kind of clunky in my opinion. I think it is safe to say that if the user grabs the mouse and moves it away from the cell that is in edit mode, they are done editing the cell. It would allow me to validate their input without requiring them to click on something first. A better user experience IMHO.

So how can I have the DataGridView automatically end edit mode on a cell when the mouse is moved a certain distance (or for a certain interval of time) away from the cell that is in edit mode?

Comment: DataGridView CellMouseLeave event?

Comment: and why would you want to set a time interval anyway.. what if the user gets distracted because of a `Phone Call` then `IMHO` your `HO` is flawed i.e `Logic`

Comment: @c4pricorn Your reputation score is 666. Kind of scary huh? Seriously, thanks but I wanted the mouse cursor to be lets say 100 pixels (for example) away to eliminate the chance that a small bump to the mouse would knock them out of edit mode while they were still typing in the cell.

Comment: @MethodMan I meant that the mouse was moved for a certain time interval -- trying to eliminate random bumps to the mouse. I realize people may pause while entering, and that is okay, I agree.

Comment: @jgayetty Developer from hell ;-) Hmm, CellMouseLeave event can start timer and end edit mode after this time. CellMouseEnter can stop timer to prevent it from unwanted editing termination...

Comment: I got it to work using CellBeginEdit event and DataGridView MouseMove. When 100 pixels away from where the cursor was on CellBeginEdit it ends edit on the cell. Works well.

Comment: That's what I thought... :-) Remember cursor position in CellBeginEdit event and calculate position after CellMouseLeave event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using the following. It works well. After ending edit I set the current cell to an uneditable cell in the same row so as to preserve row selection, but still exit the editable cell.

I also added InEditMode = false to the CellEndEdit event in case the user exits edit mode before the code does it for them.

After testing a bit I find ending edit at 50 pixels away gives a better experience than 100 pixels.

```
bool InEditMode = false;
Point EditStartLocation;

private void dgv_TimeCard_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    EditStartLocation = dgv_TimeCard.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    InEditMode = true;
}

private void dgv_TimeCard_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (InEditMode == false) return;

    int DistanceToEndEdit = 50;

    if (Math.Abs(EditStartLocation.X - e.X) > DistanceToEndEdit || Math.Abs(EditStartLocation.Y - e.Y) > DistanceToEndEdit)
    {
        dgv_TimeCard.EndEdit();
        dgv_TimeCard.CurrentCell = dgv_TimeCard.CurrentRow.Cells["Date"];
        InEditMode = false;
    }
}
private void dgv_TimeCard_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    InEditMode = false;
}
```